# what will be the mm query in TYPO3 version 9

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

As $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB'] become obsolete, I am stuck at the following mm query.

```
$dbObj = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECT_mm_query('distinct tx_news_domain_model_news.uid',
   'sys_category',
   'sys_category_record_mm',
   'tx_news_domain_model_news',
   ' AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_local IN ( '.$catUid.' ) AND tx_news_domain_model_news.pid='.$pid.' AND  sys_category_record_mm.tablenames="tx_news_domain_model_news"',
   '',
   '',
   ''
```

);
It shows
Call to a member function exec_SELECT_mm_query() on null

Has anyone found any solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the new [QueryBuilder](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/latest/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html) and join your relation.

Example (not a tested working example):

```
$table = 'tx_news_domain_model_news';
$joinTable = 'sys_category_record_mm';
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable($table);

$statement = $queryBuilder
    ->select('*')
    ->from($table)
    ->leftJoin(
        $table,
        $joinTable,
        'categoryMM',
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
            'categoryMM.uid_foreign',
            $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('tx_news_domain_model_news.uid')
        )
    )
    ->where(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('categoryMM.tablenames', $table),
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('categoryMM.fieldname', 'categories'),
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
            'categoryMM.uid',
                $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($catUid, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
            )
        )
        ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this where an older version of news has related contents stored in an MM table.

```
            $selectTable = 'tt_content';
            $joinTable = 'tx_news_domain_model_news';
            $mmTable = 'tx_news_domain_model_news_ttcontent_mm';

            /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder $queryBuilder */
            $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tt_content');

            $res = $queryBuilder->select('t.*')->from($selectTable, 't')
                ->leftJoin('t', $mmTable, 'mm',
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
                        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('mm.uid_local', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($newsRecord['uid'])),
                        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('mm.uid_foreign', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('t.uid'))
                    )
                )
                ->leftJoin('mm', $joinTable, 'n',
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('mm.uid_local', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('n.uid'))
                )
                ->where(
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->gt('n.uid', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter(0))
                )->execute()->fetchAll();
```